# Retrieving images and websites links or buttons from mysql at the same time

Tags: mysql, button, windows-phone-8, hyperlink

i m working on a project  , though m not a programming student so dont know much about it

i  have saved images and links in my database
but i want to retrieve all of them  on my app collecively ( like one image with its associated site's link) such that user can look at  image and if he wants to go to the site associated with the image, he can click on the link or button (but image and links retriving at same time )

or is there any way that buttons generate autometically according to the images retrieved  ???

"im posting this just becoz  its mandatory to post what you have tried" so copying from somewhere

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
cmd.Connection = conn
conn.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Foto FROM MyTable WHERE ID = '" & IDtxt.ToString & "'"
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While reader.Read
    If (IsDBNull(reader("Foto"))) Then
        frmCartaIdentitaView.pctImage.Image = Nothing
    Else
        Dim byteImage() As Byte = reader("Foto")
        Dim frmImageView stmFoto As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteImage)
        frmImageView.pctImage.Image = Image.FromStream(stmFoto)
        frmImageView.pctImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        frmImageView.Show()
    End If
End While
```

Comment: Are you writing an Android app or a Windows app?

Comment: windows app we are working in c# (.net)

Comment: Then why did you tag it as Android?

Comment: so you are an android developer???

Comment: are you porting this to java or something?

Comment: When you tag something as Android, all of the people who only look at Android questions see it. You shouldn't tag it that way if you're not writing an Android app.

Comment: grennis   ............... no no we are working in .net c#

Comment: carl anderson   windows app

Comment: The code is VB.Net, not C#.

Comment: its ok i dont know much about that   please tell me how to work for what i want

Comment: This site doesn't work that way. We're not writing code for you for free. You need to be able to understand programming in order to ask questions here, and be able to implement solutions described in answers.

Comment: okies bro i will try to write

Comment: actually bro m not a programming student just have to complete my task so  so for humanity you can help me out   just need a sample

Comment: My guess is that if you get a solution for this question you'll be back soon with another question. But, for the sake of humanity: you can add multiple columns in a `SELECT` statement (e.g. `SELECT Foto, Url FROM…`).

Comment: thanks venerik   thanks  from whole india   if you need any help   will always there for you